Redis instrumentation ASP.NET Core suppress logs from Activity
Currently using Redis instrumentation
otel.WithTracing(tracing => tracing.AddRedisInstrumentation("name", connection, null)) in  Program.cs to get traces and it works, but for each activity recorded four trace/log messages are written. The same goes for SEQ and Application Insights (using AzureMonitor distro)

<command> (HMGET)
ResponseReceived
Sent
Enqueued

Is there any way to remove those? I'm using Serilog and writing to OpenTelemetryLogger by setting writeToProviders: true when configuring Serilog.
Code
app.Logging.ClearProviders();
app.Logging
    .SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information)
    .AddOpenTelemetry(logger =>
    {
        logger.SetResourceBuilder(resource);
        logger.IncludeScopes = true;
        logger.IncludeFormattedMessage = true;
        logger.ParseStateValues = true;
        if (exportOtlp)
        {
            logger.AddOtlpExporter();
        }
    });
app.Host.UseSerilog((context, services, configuration) =>
    {
        configuration
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
            .ReadFrom.Services(services)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console();

        var seq = context.Configuration.GetSection("Log");
        var seqUrl = seq["SeqUrl"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(seqUrl))
        {
            Log.Logger.Warning("Missing Seq url in Log:SeqUrl, skipping writing to Seq.");
        }
        else
        {
            configuration.WriteTo.Seq(seqUrl, apiKey: seq["SeqKey"]);
        }
    },
    // Preserve logger when running tests since they are run in parallel and creates multiple
    // test hosts which will cause error setting the static logger twice.
    // Logger instance already frozen is the exception message.
    app.Configuration.GetValue<bool>("PreserveStaticLogger"),
    // Disable during tests since environment is Development and we don't want to write to Azure
    // when running tests if we have enabled it
    !app.Configuration.GetValue<bool>("SkipWriteToProviders"));

Thanks

These look like span embedded events, so I don't think you can filter them out via the Serilog configuration. Not the answer you were looking for, but on the Seq side you can use a filter on the corresponding API key that looks like @Message not in ['ResponseReceived', 'Sent', 'Enqueued'] and various more targeted versions of that. HTH!

Thanks for your answer @NicholasBlumhardt! Yeah, in SEQ I've applied some signals to filter out noise, but it would be nice if I can stop export completely. Hopefully someone from OTEL-team can shed some light over this.
Thanks also for Serilog and SEQ :-)
